# Using a non-surrogate index in an SNMP table

Tags: snmp, mib

I have `key:value` data which I want to dispay as is. Everything I've read suggests that if some column is a key then it should be `not-accessible` and thus not displayed by tools (OTOH I'm not sure that the relevant part of RFC 2579 says that, it's too hard for me to understand), but I don't want to add a surrogate key as I already have a unique key in the data. Can it be circumvented or the only accepted way is to add a surrogate identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SNMP table row key with `MAX-ACCESS not-accessible` can be displayed by tools if you wish. Look at [NetSnmp snmptable explanation](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:snmptable#Table_Indexes) ...

> ... One thing missing from the tables above, is any indication of the
>   index values for each row. The earliest MIB tables (and some more
>   recent, but poorly designed tables) did define the indexes as
>   accessible objects, which would therefore appear in the snmptable
>   output. But current MIB design has recognised that the index values
>   are included in the instance OIDs, so it is not necessary to
>   explicitly retrieve them as a separate column object.
>
> By default, the snmptable command ignores these index values, but it
>   will display them if invoked with the -Ci option.

I interpret this as meaning: since the `index` is implicit in the OID, it is sometimes unnecessary to show it, though if you are printing a whole table (using the snmptable tool) it is often handy to see it, hence NetSnmp provide the `-Ci` flag (which ignores the index's MAX-ACCESS level).

Example **without** index column shown:

```
snmptable -M +.  -m +ALL -v 2c -c public -Pu  <my server>  SNMPv2-MIB::sysORTable
SNMP table: SNMPv2-MIB::sysORTable

                                        sysORID                                              sysORDescr  sysORUpTime
          SNMP-MPD-MIB::snmpMPDMIBObjects.3.1.1         The MIB for Message Processing and Dispatching. 0:0:00:00.18
       SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmMIBCompliance         The MIB for Message Processing and Dispatching. 0:0:00:00.18
       // SNIP ...
```

Example **with** index column shown:

```
snmptable -M +.  -m +ALL -v 2c -c public -Pu -Ci  <my server>  SNMPv2-MIB::sysORTable
SNMP table: SNMPv2-MIB::sysORTable

 index                                        sysORID                                              sysORDescr  sysORUpTime
     1          SNMP-MPD-MIB::snmpMPDMIBObjects.3.1.1         The MIB for Message Processing and Dispatching. 0:0:00:00.18
     2       SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmMIBCompliance         The MIB for Message Processing and Dispatching. 0:0:00:00.18
  // SNIP ...
```